# Android widget background transparency

Tags: android, background, widget, transparent

I want to design a widget like this, in which I set some transparency on each color of gradient.

[example](http://lh5.ggpht.com/-LtIw3u237uI/TpqyEaaV6EI/AAAAAAAAAA4/VU7jrwXULlk/Weather%25252B%252520Brings%252520Stylish%252520Weather%252520Forecast%252520Widget%252520And%252520HTC%252520Sense%252520Like%252520Flip-Clock%252520On%252520Android%252520%252520%2525282%252529.jpg)

Should I use a transparent PNG image that designed on Adobe Photoshop?
9-patch?
Gradient Styles?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't plan to allow the user to change the gradient level themselves, just us a png made with PS or Gimp.

Obviously use layers to build your background on the gradients.

Comment: Is there any way to add some transparency in gradient?